# Vagrant up gives 'cygpath' Vagrant was not found in path

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I've installed Vagrant, Vagrant init worked fine. When I now run Vagrant up I get this error:

```
The executable 'cygpath' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

Im using cygwin as terminal and I have windows 8, and I've placed `C:\cygwin64\bin` in my PATH in envoirment variables.

My question is, why do I get this error message when I've specified the path to my cygwin bin?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if the given path is on your path variable? Did you try to print it to see what comes out?

Comment: can you add `p ENV['PATH']` in your Vagrantfile and make sure the PATH uses in your session is the one you set, you should see `C:\cygwin64\bin` if you added there

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming you have Cygwin installed, simply add the path to cygwin (usually c:\cygwin\bin\cygwin.exe) to your shells %path% variable and you should be ready to go.

- Ctrl-X => System => Advanced Settings => Variables
- Restart your Powershell/Cmd-Window

Comment: Paths are folders, not executables. The correct path would be the path ending in "\bin\".

Answer (score 4):

I just experienced the same error after removing cygwin, and figured out that the answer is not in reinstalling it, but simply removing it from the %Path%, so that Vagrant wouldn't search for it when booting.

So, you can open Control Panel => System => Advanced System Settings => Environment Variables...
And then find Path under System Variables, and remove any references to cygwin.

Restart your shell, and you're good to go.

Comment: This was actually my problem. I think it may be because I've had Vagrant installed in the past, or otherwise mucked about with my path. Anyway, after removing cygwin from the path Vagrant ran without issue.

Answer (score 2):

My soultion was to create a small wrapper script, `vagrant.bat`:

```
@setlocal
@set PATH=C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
@vagrant %*
@endlocal
```

The `vagrant.bat` file is in a directory that is first in my `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had the same problem and found that for some reason Cygwin had been erased from the system (I was running from git bash shell). I reinstalled Cygwin and it then worked again.